# ExtJS 2.3 - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am extending HttpProxy and pre-loading 24 Stores.  The error occurs after I add the 24th Store to be loaded, I've tried loading it on request only and the error occurs as it is called to laod.  ExtJS experts please help! I'm using ExtJS 2.3

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Ext.override.listeners.loadexception extensions.js:12
Ext.util.Event.fire ext-all-debug.js:1521
Ext.util.Observable.fireEvent
```

My little extention code in extension.js:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.HttpProxy,{
    listeners: {
        'loadexception' : function(proxy, options, response){
            var data = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");
            if (data.errorCode == "1") { //session expired or auth error
                location.reload(true);
            } else {
                this.fireEvent("loadexception",proxy,options,response);
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loadexception` **Exception handler is throwing the same exception** in `else` block`. 
So if somehow`data.errorCode`is not`1` it'll recursively call it again and again. Hence the  call stack size exceeding error.

Solution: You can do the following to prevent it,

1. Do not fire `loadexception` in the else block
2. If you fire `loadexception` make sure you change or process the response so that it does not make `data.errorCode != 1`
3. Through some other exception which handles everything.

Comment: Thank you Shiplu!  For some reason I thought the propogation of the event will stop and I needed to fire it again, since I handle the event in some cases in addition to the extension.  Thank you!